# Girth and diameter of a graph with minimum degree at least 3

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

The problem is motivated by generalizing Moore graphs, graphs with maximum possible girth ($2\text{diam}+1$) given the diameter.

**Question.** Does there exist a graph $G$ with $\text{g}(G)-\text{diam}(G)>8$ and minimum degree at least $3$, where $\text{g}(G)$ and $\text{diam}(G)$ are the girth and diameter of $G$, respectively?

**Remark.** There's an infinite class of graphs with $\text{g}(G)-\text{diam}(G)=8$: the (point,line) incidence graphs of generalized octagons have $\text{g}(G)=16$ and $\text{diam}(G)=8$.

Bonus points (+200 bounty) for a proof that $\text{g}-\text{diam}$ is unbounded for graphs with minimum degree at least $3$.

Comment: Have you checked any of the cubic cages in [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120730080521/http://mapleta.maths.uwa.edu.au/~gordon/remote/cages/index.html) for whether they give you examples?

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/q/145045

Comment: The graphs of girth 19, 20 and 22 have diameters 14, 15 and 16 respectively. The graph of girth 21 is missing.

Answer (score 7):

The recent preprint ["A randomized construction of high girth regular graphs"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.09640) by Linial and Simkin suggests in its closing remarks that the answer (at least, to your bonus question) is unknown:

> The possible relation between a graph’s girth and its diameter is particularly intriguing. It follows from [12] and Moore’s bound that
> $$2 \ge \mathrm{lim\ sup} \frac{\mathrm{girth}(G)}{\mathrm{diam}(G)} \ge 1,$$
> where the lim sup ranges over all graphs where all vertex degrees are $\ge 3$. Nothing better seems to be known at the moment.
> Even more remarkably, we do not know whether
> $$\mathrm{sup}(\mathrm{girth}(G) − \mathrm{diam}(G))$$
> is finite or not. The sup is over all $G$ in which all vertex degrees are $\ge 3$.