# Girth 5 graphs with diameter 2

Tags: graph-theory

Is there an infinite class of graphs with diameter 2, girth 5, and minimum degree at least 2?

Girth 5 is necessary, since otherwise complete bipartite graphs are an answer. Minimum degree at least 2 is necessary, since otherwise stars are an answer.

The Hoffman–Singleton graph (which has 60 vertices) is the largest graph I know with the properties in the question.

The question is interesting if "minimum degree at least 2" is replaced by "minimum degree at least 3", but I think it makes little difference because degree 2 vertices are highly restricted in a graph with diameter 2.

This question is related (but different) to the question [Girth and diameter of a graph with minimum degree at least 3](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355283/girth-and-diameter-of-a-graph-with-minimum-degree-at-least-3).

Answer (score 9):

No infinite family exists. In fact all graphs with diameter $d$ and girth $2d+1$ have to be regular, and thus are [Moore graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_graph). This was proved in

> R. Singleton, "There is no irregular Moore graph", Amer. Math. Monthly 75
> (1968), 42–43

See also the textbook "Algebraic Graph Theory" by Godsil and Royle (p. 90).
It is unknown whether the Hoffman-Singleton graph is the largest Moore graph of girth 5 but if there are more, they have to be of degree 57 and of order 3250, thus there can only be finitely many more.

Comment: I don't think it's known that there is at most one Moore graph of degree $57$?

Comment: @verret You are absolutely right.  One hears the phrase "the missing Moore graph" so often, it is easy to forget there could be more than one.

Comment: Thanks Gjergji.